# Need to store filenames in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create unique folder once i receive files from server for further processing.

When I upload the files directly onto the server it is possible to create unique folder and place files, but when i upload folder containing files it is not able to create unique folder. Can someone help me with this?

I have uploaded multiple files to the server and created unique folders.

But when I pass folder to server I am not able to create unique folders.

```
def create_unique_folder(root_dir):
    folder_name = str(uuid.uuid4())
    dir_path = root_dir + '/' + folder_name
    try:
        os.mkdir(dir_path)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.args)
        return None
    return folder_name

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        resp = {}
        files = request.files.getlist('files')
        print(files)
        #print(type(files))
        folder_name = UPLOAD_FOLDER +  create_unique_folder(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])
        if folder_name != None:
            for f in files:
                print(folder_name)
                file_path = folder_name + '/' + f.filename
                f.save(os.path.join(folder_name, f.filename))
                file = f
                print('inside upload file')
                print('file')
                filename = f.filename
                ffilename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                print(filename)
```

The above code creates unique folder as the files variable will have

files = [,  , ]

But when I upload a folder my files variable will be
files2 = [,  , ]

I think because of folder name coming in along with the filename it is not able to create unique folder.

Can someone please tell me how can I get File2 in files format?

Comment: The above code creates unique folder as the files variable will have    files = [<FileStorage: 'a2.pdf' ('application/pdf')>, <FileStorage: 's1.pdf' ('application/pdf')> , <FileStorage: 'd1.pdf' ('application/pdf')>]                                                                             But when I upload a folder my files variable will be                                 file2 = [<FileStorage: 'resumes/a2.pdf' ('application/pdf')>, <FileStorage: 'resumes/s1.pdf' ('application/pdf')> , <FileStorage: 'resumes/d1.pdf' ('application/pdf')>]

Answer (score 1):

> I think because of folder name coming in along with the filename it is not able to create unique folder.

Your description is a bit misleading - the above code does not fail *to create unique folder*, but rather to create subfolders (like `resumes/`) within it. In order to do that, you could `from pathlib import Path` and insert

```
                Path(file_path).parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

before the line `f.save(…)`.